# Does TensorFlow Object Detection API implement whiten op?

Tags: tensorflow

I am working on object detection. I want to preprocess my images by reducing RGB mean([104, 117, 123]), it is common.
So how can I do this in Object Detection API? Or I need to do this when making tfrecord?

Answer (score 0):

You could just manually transform your images and subtract/divide/etc any number in any channel by whatever you want.

Additionally, there are several ops defined that implement various image transformations. For example, have a look at [Image Adjustments](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image#Image_Adjustments). There are also predefined functions to [convert between colorspaces](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/image#Converting_Between_Colorspaces), if you want to convert RGB images to grayscale.

As a third option, you can use any imaging library in Python to preprocess your images outside of Tensorflow and feed the processed images to the graph.

Comment: Thank you. I know this adjustments. I just want to know what preprocess should I do in Object Detection API.

Answer (score 0):

Use subtract_reduce_mean preprocess config.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/protos/preprocessor.proto